# 400 (Bad Request) error

Tags: angularjs, json

Currently from Angular JS controller, I am trying to send the JSON data to backend Service. But I am having 400 Bad Request error.

From Controller, I am trying to send the data via http service like  :

```
shipDataJson.contractNumber=$scope.contractNumber;
             shipDataJson.orderNumber=$scope.orderNumber;
             shipDataJson.shipmentNumber=$scope.shipmentNumber;
             shipDataJson.SCN=$scope.SCN;
             shipDataJson.sourceSystem=$scope.selectedSrcSystem;
             shipDataJson.destinationSystem=$scope.selectedDestSystem;
             shipDataJson.resendFlag='false';
```

But, Actually at sending time JSON is like:

```
{
  "contractNumber": "abc",
  "orderNumber": "der",
  "shipmentNumber": "faas",
  "SCN": "fsdafas",
  "sourceSystem": {
    "resendFlag": false,
    "sourceSystem": "arnab"
  },
  "destinationSystem": {
    "resendFlag": false,
    "destinationSystem": "swar"
  },
  "resendFlag": "false"
}
```

Don't have the idea to remove extra "resendFlag" field from the JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have added before something. what you posted, looks correct for me. Check somewhere have added?

Comment: try to console: `$scope.selectedSrcSystem` and `$scope.selectedDestSystem`. May be here is only issue.

Comment: Can you show what this object contain, "$scope.selectedDestSystem".?? also show us where are you actually assigning this object its values

Comment: Object
resendFlag
:
false
sourceSystem
:
"arnab"

Comment: Dude you are setting 'resendFlag' here as false, it is obvious that It will be reflected in the final json, remove it from here and you will get rid of this.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `resendFlag` key. 
Just remove this line : `shipDataJson.resendFlag='false';`

Comment: Hi Steeve,  "destinationSystem": {
    "resendFlag": false,
    "destinationSystem": "swar"
  }

Comment: Oh, ok could you just log this  ? `$scope.selectedDestSystem`

Comment: Hi Steeve, I want to remove "resendFlag" from : "destinationSystem": {
    "resendFlag": false,
    "destinationSystem": "swar"
  }. several time "resendFlag" field is coming inside the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To remove properties from JavaScript objects, you `delete` them:

```
delete shipDataJson.destinationSystem.resendFlag
```

Comment: angular.js:11706TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at ChildScope.sampleModule.controller.$scope.searchShipment (ShipmentSrchCtrl.js:46)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12474)
    at callback (angular.js:21700)
    at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:14570)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:14669)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21705)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4430)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4116)

Comment: That is a separate issue. Debug your `searchShipment` function.